# Why is the vertical ScrollBar of my WPF DataGrid not displaying it's full width when contained in a Grid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, grid, scrollbar

I have a WPF usercontrol which contains a DataGrid wrapped in a grid.
The usercontrol is hosted in my main app window inside a TabControl wrapped in a StackPanel.

The issue I'm having is that I can't get the DataGrid's vertical scrollbar to fully display. It gets "clipped" so that only 1/2 it's width is visible.

**Here is the XAML definition of my UserControl:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.Views.SampleView"
             Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}},Path=ActualWidth}"
             Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}},Path=ActualHeight}">
    <Grid Name="PastDueInvoicesGrid" >
        <DataGrid Name="PastDueInvoicesDataGrid" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                Margin="0,0,0,3"  
                GridLinesVisibility="None"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                SelectionMode="Extended"
                SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                AllowDrop="False" >
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**This is what the definition of the StackPanel/TabControl looks like:**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="stackPanelAccountDetailViewContainer"
  Orientation="Vertical">
  <TabControl x:Name="tabContainerContainer"
   TabStripPlacement="Bottom" 
   Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
     AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}"
    Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
    AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}">
   </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

I've tried several different things, but I can't seem to get the Vertical Scrollbar to display it's full width. It's horizontal bounds seems to exceed the containers width.

How do I make it display correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure of the problem but generally I would avoid using StackPanel and ScrollViewer together. For me it often creates problem in how my scrollviewer behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `Width` (or `Height`) of the `TabControl` nor the `UserControl`. They will stretch to fill the parent `StackPanel` anyway:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="stackPanelAccountDetailViewContainer" Orientation="Vertical">
    <TabControl x:Name="tabContainerContainer" TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>

<UserControl x:Class="Sample.Views.SampleView">
    <Grid Name="PastDueInvoicesGrid" >
        <DataGrid Name="PastDueInvoicesDataGrid" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                Margin="0,0,0,3"  
                GridLinesVisibility="None"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                SelectionMode="Extended"
                SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                AllowDrop="False" >
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You may also try to add a `Margin` or `Padding` to the `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.Views.SampleView" ... Padding="5">
```